# clang build with c++11 with support for OSX 10.5

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, clang

I have a small c++ project that builds for windows 2000 and up and OSX 10.5 and up. Now I wanted to introduced the c++11 header file `<codecvt>` to do some conversion between std::wstring and std::string, plus I also wanted to use std::unique_ptr.

On windows everything built fine with Visual Studio 2012. On OSX 10.8 with Clang 4.2 on the other hand it did not build, it couldn't find the c++ header file. I quickly found that I needed to add the compiler flags "-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++", but then since I'm using "-mmacosx-version-min=10.5" to target OSX 10.5 I get the error:

clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires OS X 10.7 or later)

So my question is:
Is there no way of using c++11 features and targeting OSX 10.5?

Comment: Unless you *need* to use clang and `libc++`, you could use gcc instead (although the regular expressions library could be incomplete).

Comment: I tried to compile with -stdlib=libstdc++ instead of libc++. Then it does not generate an error about that it requires target to be 10.7. Instead it just do not find unique_ptr and codecvt.

Comment: Could it be that your `stdlib` is ancient? In the past I have succesfully used gcc builds from macports to compile C++11 code on mac osx.

Comment: Clang 4.2? Do you mean gcc 4.2?

Comment: No but I guess I wrote the LLVM verison..... Anyway clang --version gives this: "Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)"